# WCF app sending html response for potentially dangerous request instead of fault exception

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I added a global error handler in my `global.asax` but no matter what I try I can't seem to prevent the IIS canned response of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&amp;).</title>
...
```

I'd much rather it send a `WebFaultException` style message

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">My custom error message here</string>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into the default behavior from IIS rather than something in WCF. IIS is picking off the request before it even gets to WCF, sending back the warning. I think you can turn off the IIS request validation using something like this in the web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or this:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

Then, once the request is past IIS, you can handle the exception within WCF with a custom message inspector that checks for bad characters.

Here's a link to a document on message inspectors:

http://trycatch.me/adding-custom-message-headers-to-a-wcf-service-using-inspectors-behaviors/